# Error message for one model when trying to run two almost identical pgls models

Tags: r, linear-regression, phylogeny

I'm trying to create a model using the `pgls()` function in the package `caper` to look at the impact of feeding style on shape.  The model below works:

```
latdata <- comparative.data(lattree, lat, Species, vcv=TRUE, vcv.dim=3)
latpigot <- pgls(PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 + PC5 + PC6 + PC7 ~ Feeding, latdata, lambda = 'ML')
```

Where `lattree` is my phylogenetic tree, `lat` is my dataset and `Species`, the PCs and `Feeding` are the names of columns in my dataset.  The PCs are numerical variables with positive and negative values.  `Species` and `Feeding` are categorical variables.

But when I try the same code with a new dataset and new tree it does not work and I get an error:

```
vendata <- comparative.data(ventree, ven, Species, vcv=TRUE, vcv.dim=3)
venpigot <- pgls(PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 + PC5 + PC6 + PC7 ~ Feeding, vendata, lambda = 'ML')

Error in pgls(PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 + PC5 + PC6 + PC7 ~ Feeding, vendata,  : 
  Problem with optim:52ERROR: ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH
```

`ven` has 65 entries instead of the 66 in `lat`.  The trees are the same except that one of the taxa in `lattree` is not in `ventree`.

From what I understand, the `pgls()` function has the `optim()` function somewhere in its code and that's what's causing the issues but I don't understand how the `optim()` function fits in and why it might be causing issues.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be going wrong?

Many thanks,

Carolina

EDIT:
If I set `lambda` to 1, this seems to work.  However, I don't know if this is right or how to decide on appropriate `lambda` value.  Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this webpage:

http://blog.phytools.org/2012/11/fitting-model-in-phylogenetic.html

and used the `ape` and `nlme` packages to write a PGLS model using this code:

```
venpigot <- gls(PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 + PC5 + PC6 + PC7 ~ Pigot, ven, correlation = corPagel(1, ventree, fixed = FALSE), method = "ML")
```

which seems to work.